# Creating .desktop file

Tags: command-line, vnc, vncviewer, .desktop

I have tried to create a .desktop file to run vncviewer (tight vnc connecting to a mac). I have entered below into the file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=x.y
Name=VNCViewer
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=/usr/bin/vncviewer 10.0.1.5:5900
Terminal=true
```

When I double click the file it returns "There was an error launching the application."

Any suggestions what I have done wrong in my .desktop file?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found what the problem was.

**You are missing one entry in the file. Place the following entry into the file**

```
Type=Application
```

After you save the file, you'll notice it's icon change to look more like an application than what is looks like now (a text/script file).

Even if you make the file executable Ubuntu Desktop doesn't know if this file is a script or application and assumes it's a script. But if you place the Type=Application it will run it fine.

Comment: Have a look at [Arronax](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax/) for a GUI to create .desktop files

Comment: `gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new path/to/folder` is useful...

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
Path=/path/to/directory
```

may be required if the application requires the user to start the executable binary in a certain directory. That was the case for me when just compiling a program from source but not installing system-wide.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give this a try: `Exec=bash -c "/usr/bin/vncviewer 10.0.1.5:5900"`

Also make sure your .desktop file is executable. `chmod +x your_file.desktop`